# I want the sum not the string, how?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

This gives me the string: "01234" instead of 1+2+3+4=10, why?
I'd like to get the sum of the numbers not of the string.
Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=1;
var totale=0;
var index = Array();
var domanda = 0;

while (domanda !== "end") {
domanda = prompt("Write a number, the total so far is: "+totale);
index[i]=domanda;
totale += index[i];
i++;
}

document.writeln("total: " + totale);

document.writeln("ended");

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `prompt()` (which you should not be using) returns a string.
Wrapping the return in a `parseInt(domanda)` would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
index[i]=Number(domanda);
```

Full script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=1;
var totale=0;
var index = Array();
var domanda = 0;

do {
    domanda = prompt("Write a number, the total so far is: "+totale);
    if (domanda !== "end" && !isNaN(Number(domanda)))
    {
        index[i]=Number(domanda);
        totale += index[i];
        i++;
    }
} while (domanda !== "end")

document.writeln("total: " + totale);

document.writeln("ended");

</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks. I tried using also ParseInt. Still a problem: whenever I enter into prompt the string "end" the total comes out NaN. total: NaN ended. I do not understand why, the while condition should avoid adding the last "end" into the totale variable.

Comment: @passegua I edited my answer with some changes. Plz check if it is what you want. Why you are using an Array? you can do exactly the same thing without the array

Answer (score 0):

You need to `parseInt` the value coming back from the prompt, otherwise you're concatenating strings.

`index[i]= parseInt(domanda);`

You'll probably want to check whether the input value is a number too.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's built in `parseInt`, this creates an int of anything passed into it, so: `parseInt(value);`